# How to add my own color list in quill editor font-color menu?

Tags: javascript, vaadin, quill

I have added Quill Editor as Vaadin component so i can access it in Java and i have customized it little bit because all i need is **BOLD**, *ITALIC* and font-color buttons and that is working fine.

I am struggling with one thing. I want to set my own colors and only mine in color-menu. How can i achieve this?

in my custom quilleditor.js i have this:

```
const ColorClass = Quill.import('attributors/class/color');
Quill.register(ColorClass, true);
const ColorStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/color');
Quill.register(ColorStyle, true);
```

which i think basically somehow imports this from node_modules/quill/themes/base.js :

```
const COLORS = [
  "#000000", "#e60000", "#ff9900", "#ffff00", "#008a00", "#0066cc", "#9933ff",
  "#ffffff", "#facccc", "#ffebcc", "#ffffcc", "#cce8cc", "#cce0f5", "#ebd6ff",
  "#bbbbbb", "#f06666", "#ffc266", "#ffff66", "#66b966", "#66a3e0", "#c285ff",
  "#888888", "#a10000", "#b26b00", "#b2b200", "#006100", "#0047b2", "#6b24b2",
  "#444444", "#5c0000", "#663d00", "#666600", "#003700", "#002966", "#3d1466"
];
```

because the color-menu looks exactly like this and the count and the colors match the list above:

[image]

How can i get rid of those colors and add my own list when creating the editor?

I have tried using whitelist but with no success.

I am totally not a javascript developer and i am trying to do something i dont fully understand thus i ask for help.

Comment: How are you initializing the editor? Because Quill provides some customizeability for the colors inside the [toolbar](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/) module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me into right direction ! 
What i had was this: this.colors = [{ 'color': [] }]; 

And the website you just showed says "Note Themes may also specify default values for dropdowns. For example, Snow provides a default list of 35 colors for the color and background formats, if set to an empty array." So i added my colors to the array and it works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Mari It's perfectoy fine to provide your own answer on SO. This helps other users with the same problem to find the answer easier than just some comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Ian H. i figured it out.

While initializing editor i had this:

`this.colors = [{ 'color': [] }];`

And according to https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/
"Themes may also specify default values for dropdowns. For example, Snow provides a default list of 35 colors for the color and background formats, if set to an empty array."

So i just added my colors to the array:

`this.colors = [{ 'color': ['#e60000', '#9933ff', '#00ff00'] }];`

and it works! Thanks a lot :)